how to add marker to osmroid map
I put the marker attribute to map.getOverlays().add(marker) but they are saying add metgod requre attribute drawable not a marker.
The currentMarker is a Marker universal verable.
 ` private void addMarker(GeoPoint point) {
    map.getController().setCenter(point);
        if(drawableMarker==null){
            drawableMarker =new Drawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.markerosm);
        }
    if (currentMarker != null) {
      map.getOverlay().remove(currentMarker);
    }

    currentMarker = new Marker(map);
    currentMarker.setPosition(point);
    currentMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
        
    map.getOverlay().add(currentMarker);

    map.invalidate();
  }`

I want the marker will set on osmdroid map.

use this code :
            Marker marker = new Marker(mapView);
            marker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(lat, lng));
            marker.setTitle(yourTitle);
            marker.setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
            mapView.getOverlays().add(marker);

mapView is instance of org.osmdroid.views.MapView
